# R translation into SQL gap fill

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

I have a R script that I need to migrate into SQL. In R I can use the tidyr::complete to fill in the gaps no worries. And when I know I can do it in SQL with the cross join function. the problem arises when I want to maintain some of the nulls that exist.
I reduced the results here for simplicity but the sequence would go

- if month1 = 2012-01-01 then month2 would sequence every month from 2012-01-01 until today month
- if month1 = 2020 then month2 would sequence from 2020-01-01 to 2022-11-01

| month1 | month2 | units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-01-01 | null | 10 |
| 2012-01-01 | 2012-01-01 | null |
| 2012-01-01 | 2012-03-01 | 15 |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-01-01 | 12 |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-04-01 | 17 |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-05-05 | 5 |

Ideally I would get

| month1 | month2 | units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-01-01 | null | 10 |
| 2012-01-01 | 2012-01-01 | null |
| 2012-01-01 | 2012-02-01 | null |
| 2012-01-01 | 2012-03-01 | 15 |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-01-01 | 12 |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-02-01 | null |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-03-01 | null |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-04-01 | 17 |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-05-05 | 5 |

but in SQL I am getting

| month1 | month2 | units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-01-01 | 2012-01-01 | null |
| 2012-01-01 | 2012-02-01 | null |
| 2012-01-01 | 2012-03-01 | 15 |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-01-01 | 12 |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-02-01 | null |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-03-01 | null |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-04-01 | 17 |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-05-05 | 5 |

```sql
SELECT
    seq.*
    , COALESCE(m.n, 0) AS termed
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT month1
        FROM table1
        WHERE submit_dt IS NOT NULL
    ) sign
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT month2
        FROM table1
        WHERE submit_dt IS NOT NULL
    )
    WHERE month2 >= mmonth1 and month2 is not null
) seq
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        t2.month1,
        , t2.month2
        , COUNT(*) AS units
    FROM table2 t2
    GROUP BY 1,2
) u ON u.month1 = seq.month1 AND u.month2 = seq.month2
```

Here is the R version that gives me what I want

```html
df
<- (month1, month2, units) %>% 
group_by(month1) %>% 
tidyr::complete(month2 = seq.Date(as.Date("2012-01-01"), floor_date(today(), "month"), "month"))
```

Any help is appreciated. I know it is something super simple I am missing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So you want the gaps filled for month year 2012 from 2012-01-01 - currentdate

and the same goes for every year in month1

the foolowing extract first all unique years in the month1 generates all dates from the extract year till now and joins it to the orignal table

```
CREATE TABLE tab1
    ("month1" timestamp, "month2" timestamp, "units" varchar(4))
;
    
INSERT INTO tab1
    ("month1", "month2", "units")
VALUES
    ('2012-01-01', NULL, '10'),
    ('2012-01-01', '2012-01-01', NULL),
    ('2012-01-01', '2012-03-01', '15'),
    ('2012-01-01', '2013-01-01', '12'),
    ('2012-01-01', '2013-04-01', '17'),
    ('2012-01-01', '2013-05-05', '5'),
  ('2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '5')
;
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

> ```
> INSERT 0 7
> ```

```
SELECT s.date1
     ,COALESCE(t."month2",s.date2) as month2
  ,t."units"
FROM  (
      SELECT (t._year || '-01-01')  ::date as date1, generate_series( (t._year || '-01-01')  ::date
                        , (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE) || '-12-01') ::date
                        , interval '1 month'
          )::date AS date2
   FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT
extract(year from "month1") _year FROM tab1) t
   ) s
LEFT   JOIN tab1 t 
  ON date_trunc('month',t."month1"::date)::date = s.date1 
  AND date_trunc('month',t."month2"::date)::date = s.date2   
ORDER  BY 1,2;
```

| date1 | month2 | units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-01-01 | 2012-01-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2012-02-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2012-03-01 00:00:00 | 15 |
| 2012-01-01 | 2012-04-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2012-05-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2012-06-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2012-07-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2012-08-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2012-09-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2012-10-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2012-11-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2012-12-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 | 12 |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-02-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-03-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-04-01 00:00:00 | 17 |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-05-05 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-06-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-07-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-08-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-09-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-10-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-11-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-12-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2014-01-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2014-02-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2014-03-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2014-04-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2014-05-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2014-06-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2014-07-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2014-08-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2014-09-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2014-10-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2014-11-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2014-12-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2015-01-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2015-02-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2015-03-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2015-04-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2015-05-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2015-06-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2015-07-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2015-08-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2015-09-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2015-10-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2015-11-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2015-12-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2016-02-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2016-03-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2016-04-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2016-05-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2016-06-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2016-07-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2016-08-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2016-09-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2016-10-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2016-11-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2016-12-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2017-02-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2017-03-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2017-04-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2017-05-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2017-06-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2017-07-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2017-08-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2017-09-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2017-10-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2017-11-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2017-12-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2018-03-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2018-04-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2018-05-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2018-06-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2018-07-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2018-08-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2018-09-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2018-10-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2018-11-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2018-12-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2019-02-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2019-03-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2019-04-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2019-05-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2019-06-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2019-07-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2019-09-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2019-10-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2019-11-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2019-12-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2020-02-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2020-03-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2020-04-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2020-05-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2020-06-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2020-07-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2020-08-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2020-11-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2021-04-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2021-05-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2021-06-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2021-08-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2021-09-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2021-10-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2021-11-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2021-12-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2022-03-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2022-04-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2022-05-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2022-06-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2022-10-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2022-11-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2012-01-01 | 2022-12-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-02-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-03-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-04-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-05-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-06-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-07-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-08-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-11-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2021-04-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2021-05-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2021-06-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2021-08-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2021-09-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2021-10-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2021-11-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2021-12-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2022-03-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2022-04-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2022-05-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2022-06-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2022-10-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2022-11-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-01-01 | 2022-12-01 00:00:00 | *null* |

> ```
> SELECT 168
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/U4I68jIM)

Comment: Almost. 

What I need it to do is more like
for every instance where month1 is not null and month2 is null and units is not null

leave it how it is

when month2 is missing and units is null then gap fill

Comment: In the 'ideally I would get' example shows what I mean.

where there are events that all month2 to remain null

Inn the table you made I lose the two with 10 units

VALUES
    ('2012-01-01', NULL, '10')
is not in the output table